# ruby (for rails) sort_by instantiated variable

Tags: ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In a rails 3.2.17 application, with ruby 1.9.3, a method filters a previously-found set of  **products** based on a condition. If it passes the condition, it creates an instance variable for the record (**rate**), which itself is the product of another method (**shown_price**).

```
@products = @inventories.map(&:product).uniq

def validarray
  validarray = Array.new
  @products.each do |product|
    @inventories_for_product = @inventories.select{ |i| i.product_id == product.id }
    if @inventories_for_product.count == @threshhold
      product.rate = @inventories_for_product.map(&@shown_price).inject(0, :+)
      validarray << product
    end
  end
  validarray.sort_by{|p| p[:rate]}
end
@validarray = validarray
```

All elements in this method generate proper data which can be viewed via the browser.  In fact (even re-calling sort_by)

```
<% @validarray.sort_by{|p| p[:rate]}.each do |vp| %>
  <%= vp.id %> <%= vp.rate %><br />
<% end %>
```

will show the proper data.

**Issue** when I ask for descending order

```
@validarray.sort_by{|p| -p[:rate]}
```

> undefined method `-@' for nil:NilClass

whereas for ascending order
no complaints, but no sorting either.

I assume that the symbol 
    :rate  is wrong 
and ruby lets the stuff unsorted as ASC is invoked by default and has nothing to sort with, but complains otherwise because it has no tools in its hands.

Comment: This mean that your product has no `rate` attribute or that it is null for all the records. Just to clarify: does it sort in one way?

Comment: No, it does not sort, even on suggested answer.  And, referring to first answer, all products have a rate value; they are rendered in the view.  I suspect it is being ignored for some syntaxic reason.

Comment: Is `rate` a column in a database or is it defined as a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you`rate` attribute is not a column in `products` table, but it is defined as a method within `Product` model. This means that `[]` method on the model will always return `nil`, as it only reads given database column and perform a typecast. In short, do:

```
@validarray.sort_by &:rate
```

or (in reverse order)

```
@validarray.sort_by{|p| -p.rate }
```

Comment: Bingo! Yes it is a method (inventories table for app contextual purposes) and not a column.

Comment: @Jerome - Cool. I would recommend posting some of your code to http://codreview.stackexchange.com. You are using array methods on ActiveRecord relations which may have a terrible impact on the performance of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the observation.  I've actually been keeping an eye on this matter, with a big DB (1.2 mio records) and a major stress test (invoking about 1k of those).  For practical reasons of generating faster postgres results,  the database structure requires running a conditional find first (via rails AR query).  Then I take the found set and re-filter it with (can't be done in the first step as the filter condition is non existent) with the array method, then sort. In practice it has not affected performance  (pagination is however VERY required!). Result of the typo for codreview, is grand!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly not all products have a `:rate` value. You could either:

```
@validarray.sort_by{|p| p[:rate]}.reverse
```

or:

```
@validarray.sort_by{|p| -(p[:rate] || 0) }
```